# не получается добавить колонку в конец таблицы mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных

подскажите пожалуйста, я в mysql совсем зелёный еще, мне в созданную таблицу нужно добавить колонку timestamp. пишу вот такой запрос:

```
ALTER TABLE 'users' ADD COLUMN time_stamp TIMESTAMP(14) NOT NULL DEFAUL now();
```

и выдаёт такую ошибку:  `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;`
я то понимаю, что ошибка в синтаксисе, но в чём именно? гуглил, вроде правильно пишу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строка данных именем таблицы являться не может. Внимание на кавычки, они ставятся не просто так и имеют свой смысл.

```
'users'
```

это строка данных

```
`users`
```

Это имя идентификатора - таблицы, поля и т.д.

```
"users"
```

В зависимости от [`sql_mode`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes). Если ANSI_QUOTES включен, то это идентификатор, если выключен - строка данных.

Comment: спасибо, я забыл про эту особенность. Кавычки не нужно было ставить вообще)